# Variable that should have the same value as string, but doesn't

Tags: python

I print the variable `temp` which gets the result of
 `return "%s %s %s" % (self.subject, self.verb, self.object)`

So, my problem is, when I print `temp`it says: `player tell joke`
But, if I say: `if 'player tell joke' == temp:`
The program won't go inside the if.

What I want to know is possible reasons on why this would happen.
It's a bit complicated as there's more than one module... But here's a bit of code

```
temp = lexicon.scan(form.action)    
temp = parser.parse_sentence(temp)
print temp  
if 'player tell joke' == temp:
    print temp
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: try `print(repr(temp))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands It gave me this: <gothonweb.parser.Sentence object at 0x031CE190>

Comment: Buggy code is the reason. :) def return_var(subject, verb, obj):
    return "%s %s %s" % (subject, verb, obj)

temp = return_var('player', 'tell', 'joke')
if 'player tell joke' == temp:
    print("success") 

will return success. Your problem is that `temp` is not a string, but a Sentence object. There should be a way to go from this object to the string it contains

Comment: @Uvar str(temp) did it, thank you!

Comment: @Chris_Rands I liked your comment, learned something new, thanks!

Comment: Moved to answers then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buggy code is the reason. :)

```
def return_var(subject, verb, obj): 
    return "%s %s %s" % (subject, verb, obj) 
temp = return_var('player', 'tell', 'joke') 
if 'player tell joke' == temp: 
    print("success")
```

will return "success". Your problem is that temp is not a string, but a Sentence object. There should be a way to go from this object to the string it contains, for example `str(temp)`.